# Do Nikon D-100 lenses fit a D-90?

Tags: lens, nikon-d90

Do the lenses that fit a Nikon D-100 also fit a Nikon D-90 camera body?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes. Do not think about them as D100 lenses. [They are Nikon F-Mount lenses](http://www.neocamera.com/list_lenses.php?mount=nikon).**

The D100 is Nikon DSLR with a 1.5X sensor crop and will work with any F-mount lens. This includes the Nikkor, Sigma, Tokina, Tamron, etc. Additionally, the D90 and D100 have a built-in focus motor, so autofocus works with AF and AF-S lenses.

Answer (score 2):

@Ital, Almost.

It will work with any F-mount lens from the 1980s on. Many of the first Nikkor F-mount lenses have a tang to connect to the old-style meters. This tang will have interference issues with many modern bodies.

I happen to have a half dozen or more pre-AI Nikkor lenses that won't mount of many modern Nikon bodies.

Comment: yes, he should have said Ai-s and newer (and most Ai as well).